# Ruby: How to make a method for additive inverse of an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method that when you pass an array to it, a new array is created that is its additive inverse (EX: [1,2,3,4] => (additive inverse) [-1,-2,-3,-4].  I've tried including Enumerable as well as putting .each. I have also gotten rid of .map and then I'm left with undefined method 'x'. I have played around with the code multiple times as well as researched several sites on how to operate on each element within an array as it's passed to a method. The closest I have been is this:

```
def add_inv (x) 

  arr_new = x.map {|e| -e}
  puts arr_new

end

add_inv([5,-7,8,3])
```

Output:

```
-5
7
-8
-3
```

I'm looking for the output to be in array form. 
Desired output: [-5, 7, -8, -3]

Thank you in advance for positive feedback & criticism.
(new to Ruby)

EDIT: 12:29 - 4/13/2020
While playing further with the code and some suggestions below I was able to manipulate an array with the following code and will continue to work on coming up with a method that will allow you to pass an array as an argument and then turn it into the inverse array.  Here is the code that gave me the desired output (still not a method though).

```
b = Array.new ([5,-7,8,3].map{|v| v*(-1)})

p b
```

Output: [-5,7,-8,-3]

Will update once I figure out how to do this with a method.

Comment: can you add your desired output?

Comment: What is the "additive inverse of an array"? Arrays and concatenation do not form a ring, so I don't think something like the "additive inverse of an array" even exists! Intuitively, the additive inverse `i` of an array `a` would be the array which, when concatenated with `a` yields the empty array. This is obviously impossible.

Comment: [`Array#map()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) is the `x` function you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean with _matrix form_? What is the _matrix form_ of an array?

Comment: I have added edits to the original post based on the comments I've received.  Feel free to review and respond with new information. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, misunderstood your question the first time, the problem here is that `puts` treat different arrays when you try to show them, you can then use `p` or `print` to do what you want, here are the examples

```
def add_inv_with_puts(x) 
  puts x.map {|e| -e}
end
add_inv_with_puts([5,-7,8,3])

def add_inv_with_p(x) 
  p x.map {|e| -e}
end
add_inv_with_p([5,-7,8,3])

def add_inv_with_print(x) 
  print x.map {|e| -e}
end
add_inv_with_print([5,-7,8,3])
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `.map{|v| -v}`? (no parenthesis around `v`)

Comment: When I originally looked this up I found this answer as well, but I wasn't quite sure who to interpret this and transform it above into a method that I could use over and over again.  The above seems that you have to write it all out on whatever array you want to use.  Where I'd like to do more of what I originally posted with creating a method for any array.

Comment: @axiac there is no difference, I just misunderstood the question, my bad

Comment: Thank you! I've added all three of those examples to document. Extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After fooling around with the code some more based on what other posted, I was able to get a method working for any arrays.

```
def add_inv (x)

  #b = Array.new (not needed)
  b = x.map{|v| -v}
  p b

end


add_inv([1,2,3,4])
add_inv([5,-7,8,3])
```

Output: 
[-1, -2, -3, -4]
[-5, 7, -8, -3]

Thank you for the information and pushes in the right direction.

Comment: The first line of your method is useless: you assign `b`, but then you re-assign it on the next line without ever doing anything with `b`, so you can just delete the first line.

Comment: Thank you. Originally I thought that I needed to state that b was going to be an array. Thank you for the correction, makes sense.